# How to submit POST request via API

Tags: json, api

I did some searching and haven't come across anything for what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to apply for a new job and there is an option to apply by API. This is new to me so I thought I would give it a try and pick up some learning along the way. I have some understanding of front end development but no experience with JSON. The API instructions are quoted as saying "Simply submit a POST request to our careers endpoint with a raw JSON request body, as shown, and we’ll get back to you!"

```
POST https://contact.companyname.com/jobs

{
"name": "Jane Doe",
"email": "jane@hotmail.com",
"resume": "www.linktoresume.com",
"github": "github.com/jane", // optional
"twitter": "@jane", // optional
"website": "jane.com" // optional
}
```

For someone without any understanding of where to even start with this, is there a write up on how to start or accomplish this?

Comment: You need an application that sends the request for you. See curl or postman.

Comment: was this a job application for Plaid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To send an API request you need to use a REST client. A popular client is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), they have a lot of great documentation which makes it easy to use.

Also, another method which might be easier is to use curl to send the request. Curl is used on the command line in your terminal. It comes pre-installed on Linux and MacOS or can be downloaded.

Once you have curl you can send your request like this:

`curl -d '{"name":"Jane Doe", "email": "jane@hotmail.com", "resume": "www.linktoresume.com", "github": "github.com/jane", "twitter": "@jane", "website": "jane.com"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://contact.companyname.com/jobs`

Answer (score 0):

There are many `clients` using which you can send `http` request .i suggest install [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and use `http Post` method to make a request .Ofcourse when you choose Post method you can paste this `json` as `raw` under body .don't forget to change text to `application/json`.